# In Office 365, what are the minimum permission for developers to be able to develop provider hosted-app

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-addin, office-365, administration

I am working on Office 365 project, and i have 2 developers working as an out-sourced inside the project. now i want those 2 developers to be ale to developer and test some Provider-Hosted applications. so i did the following:-

1. i create 2 developer site collections. and inside each site collection i added one of the developers inside the site collection administration group.
2. Also inside the app catalog site collection i grant the users contribute permission to be able to upload apps.

so can anyone advice if the developers need any additional permission, on the tenant level ? or being the admin of the developer site collection + a contributor on the app catalog site collection should be sufficient to develop provider-hosted apps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do not think users with contribute permission can upload Apps inside the app catalogue, they need at least Edit..

Answer (score 1):

Mostly I guess these permissions are enough for your application development lifecycle.

However, if your app needs to do some stuff at the tenant level(for example, create or delete site collections) , then you need to have SharePoint admin permissions.

Check below screenshot related to tenant permission -

[image]